# Use Stripe webhooks and AWS API Gateway + Lambda to update flag in DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, stripe-payments, aws-api-gateway

I have a website with a submission form that writes to a DynamoDB table and sets a default "Paid" flag to `false`.

This is a snippet from the frontend to give you a sense of the field names:

```
const Home: React.FC = () => {
  const [file, setFile] = useState<File | null>(null);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>('');
  const [petName, setPetName] = useState<string>('');
  const [videoKey, setVideoKey] = useState<string>('');
  const [isUploading, setIsUploading] = useState<boolean>(false);
```

I want to have a Stripe webhook monitor for successful payment, and when the payment is successful, update the Paid flag to `true`.

I am using AWS API Gateway and Lambda.

This is my Lambda code:

```
// index.mjs
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import Stripe from 'stripe';

// Initialize Stripe with your secret key
const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY, { apiVersion: '2020-08-27' });

// Initialize AWS SDK
const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

// Helper function to update the 'paid' status in DynamoDB
const updatePaymentStatus = async (userId, videoId, paidStatus) => {
  const params = {
    TableName: 'petsafaritable1', // Your DynamoDB table name
    Key: { userId, videoId },
    UpdateExpression: 'set paid = :p',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':p': paidStatus,
    },
  };
  return dynamoDB.update(params).promise();
};

export const handler = async (event) => {
  let stripeEvent;

  try {
    // Verify the event with Stripe to make sure it's legitimate
    const sig = event.headers['Stripe-Signature'];
    stripeEvent = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(event.body, sig, process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
    return {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: `Webhook Error: ${err.message}`,
    };
  }

  // Handle the event
  if (stripeEvent.type === 'payment_intent.succeeded') {
    const paymentIntent = stripeEvent.data.object;
    const userId = paymentIntent.metadata.userId;
    const videoId = paymentIntent.metadata.videoId;

    try {
      // Update the 'paid' status in DynamoDB to true
      await updatePaymentStatus(userId, videoId, true);
      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({ received: true }),
      };
    } catch (updateError) {
      console.error(`Error updating payment status in DynamoDB: ${updateError.message}`);
      return {
        statusCode: 500,
        body: `Error updating payment status in DynamoDB: ${updateError.message}`,
      };
    }
  } else {
    // Ignore other event types
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: `Received unhandled event type: ${stripeEvent.type}`,
    };
  }
};
```

I am 99% sure I have the env vars set correctly in Lambda.

I have `petsafari-stripepaywebhook` API Gateway set up as well.

I took the invoke URL (`https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod`) and loaded as a webhook listening for all checkout events.

But when I checkout with test credentials (4242...), my Stripe dashboard says "The webhook delivery failed."

```
HTTP status code
404 (Not Found)

{
  "message": "Not Found"
}

Request

{
  "id": "evt_1OFml3Ej3GI2oYw2vCQ7n6RW",
  "object": "event",
  "api_version": "2023-10-16",
  "created": 1700783793,
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "cs_test_a17a7e6ZPoUum328HbhqKEiecNa6WcRiHi1TEubvfK00n9bih2mninhSLe",
      "object": "checkout.session",
      "after_expiration": null,
      "allow_promotion_codes": null,
      "amount_subtotal": 2000,
      "amount_total": 2000,
      "automatic_tax": {
        "enabled": false,
        "status": null
      },
      "billing_address_collection": null,
      "cancel_url": "https://www.petsafari.tv/payment-cancelled",
      "client_reference_id": null,
      "client_secret": null,
      "consent": null,
      "consent_collection": null,
      "created": 1700783771,
      "currency": "usd",
      "currency_conversion": null,
      "custom_fields": [
      ],
      "custom_text": {
        "shipping_address": null,
        "submit": null,
        "terms_of_service_acceptance": null
      },
      "customer": null,
      "customer_creation": "if_required",
      "customer_details": {
        "address": {
          "city": null,
          "country": "US",
          "line1": null,
          "line2": null,
          "postal_code": "12345",
          "state": null
        },
        "email": "this@that.com",
        "name": "chri sdes",
        "phone": null,
        "tax_exempt": "none",
        "tax_ids": [
        ]
      },
      "customer_email": null,
      "expires_at": 1700870171,
      "invoice": null,
      "invoice_creation": {
        "enabled": false,
        "invoice_data": {
          "account_tax_ids": null,
          "custom_fields": null,
          "description": null,
          "footer": null,
          "metadata": {
          },
          "rendering_options": null
        }
      },
      "livemode": false,
      "locale": null,
      "metadata": {
      },
      "mode": "payment",
      "payment_intent": "pi_3OFml2Ej3GI2oYw212TKJpIv",
      "payment_link": null,
      "payment_method_collection": "if_required",
      "payment_method_configuration_details": null,
      "payment_method_options": {
      },
      "payment_method_types": [
        "card"
      ],
      "payment_status": "paid",
      "phone_number_collection": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "recovered_from": null,
      "setup_intent": null,
      "shipping_address_collection": null,
      "shipping_cost": null,
      "shipping_details": null,
      "shipping_options": [
      ],
      "status": "complete",
      "submit_type": null,
      "subscription": null,
      "success_url": "https://www.petsafari.tv/payment-success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
      "total_details": {
        "amount_discount": 0,
        "amount_shipping": 0,
        "amount_tax": 0
      },
      "ui_mode": "hosted",
      "url": null
    }
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "pending_webhooks": 3,
  "request": {
    "id": null,
    "idempotency_key": null
  },
  "type": "checkout.session.completed"
}
```

I'm not sure how to start debugging this. Does anyone see where this may be failing? The frontend form is successfully creating the initial DynamoDB entry, but the webhook is failing and the paid flag is not being updated to `true`.

EDIT:
The custom stage is indeed set to /prod:
[image]

Here are my routes:
[image]

Comment: It returns 404, which means that your URL is not found. Forget stripe, try your URL with `curl` and see what it returns (I suspect 404, which does not go from your code, but from API Gateway itself). Probably that `/prod` should not be there: if you don't use custom stages, `$default` is accessible without path prefix. So, if that URL returns 404 in you terminal, try to find the correct URL first, and only then set it as some listener somwhere, be it Stripe or whatever. (nice question BTW - not a MRE, but enough to see that 404 does not come from your server code)

Comment: @STerliakov - thanks - I updated the original post to show that I did indeed set the custom stage to `/prod`. I have not been able to successfully curl. Trying more permutations...

Comment: What path in APIGateway maps to your lambda integration? Post that page as well.

Comment: @STerliakov - updated. This is making me thinking I am forgetting some basic part of this? Did I not set up my routes correctly?

Comment: In this setup, your endpoint URL is `https://xxxxxxx.execute-.../prod/petsafarilambda-StripeWebhookHandler`, why do you expect something in the root? (And why such a long name, but it's up to you)

Comment: Thanks. Updating the URL to that in Stripe seems to do something, as now I get a different error in Stripe -- it says Webhook delivery failed, and "  "message": "Internal Server Error"". (Re: the naming, named it the same as the repo with the code, it helps me remember.)

Comment: Yes, now it's much better: instead of debugging API Gateway you're actually debugging your code. Check lambda logs in Cloudwatch to shed some light on this problem. Perhaps it's a lambda execution role missing DynamoDB permissions, but maybe something else as well.